# transistor replacement with parameters -ft/power dissipation difference?

Tags: power-supply, transistors

i am trying to fix a 400w power supply, 16v is going through a 1.5k/0.5w resistor,to h945p npn transistors then to driving transformer, reading of h945 p is short. i want to replace it,the shops here dont have it even after i say the values from data sheet ,they are so dumb. i am getting this ST2SC1815 for a cheaper price ,almost similar parameters except these 2 - ft is 250 for h495p ,80 for ST2SC1815 power dissipation is 250mW for h495p , 400mW for ST2SC1815

can i replace h495p with ST2SC1815 ? thanks

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your question is difficult to read. From first view it seems to be a repair question or a question asking for product recommendations. Both are considered off-topic because their use for other users is very limited. Please reformat it and rethink if you can elaborate the underlying engineering problem. Otherwise your post will probably be deleted.

Comment: yes its a repair question and i am asking if it can be replaced?i am sorry , i dont know how else to rephrase it,i have entered the difference of 2 components.. npn transistor.

Comment: ft and power dissipation are the difference between 2 components ,others are same,so i wanted to know if i can replace it?